# set.remove vs list.remove (function binding)

Tags: java, list, set

I am new to java. It seems really simple but I can't understand why this is happening.

```
for (int i = -3; i < 3; i++){
    set.add(i);
    list.add(i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    set.remove(i);
    list.remove(i);
}
```

When they print themselves, set prints [-3, -2, -1](desired output) whereas list prints [-2, 0, 2](Not desired output).
For list.remove() method, since it is overloading it considers its argument as index, not object. Is this right? Why is this happening and how do I fix list to print desired output using function binding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set.remove(Object)` removes the element that is equals to the `Object` param while `List.remove(int index)` removes the elements at the index parameter.

Note that  `remove(int index);` is defined in the `List` but not in `Set` interface as  the `Set` interface doesn't have a specific order for elements.

The compiler chooses the method that matches the more with the declared type of the argument. And for a `List`, `remove(int index);` is which one that matches more to an `int`.
Concerning the `Set.remove()` invocation, the compiler bounds the method to `Set.remove(Object)` because that is the single possibility and that the boxing feature allows to convert a `int` to an `Integer` at compile time.

So as said by Aomine, what you are looking for is  :

```
list.remove((Integer) i)
```

Because in this case for the compiler the two methods are eligible but it chooses `remove(Object obj);` as it is more specific than  `remove(int index);` for an `Integer` declared type parameter passed.

Comment: @Aomine. Indeed. That is probably what he/she looks for. I updated consequently. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because `List` provides two flavours of `remove()`

1) `remove(Object)`

2) `remove(index)`

When `int` is passed to `remove` the second one is called.

Solution;

`list.remove(new Integer(i))`